# How to disable the device orientation permission dialog and the enter VR button

Tags: aframe

I've been trying to disable both using the `device-orientation-permission-ui` and `vr-mode-ui` components but I couldn't get it working as expected. Below the relevant part of the HTML and a [glitch with a runnable version](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/bottlenose-jumpy-muscle?path=index.html%3A124%3A7)

```html
<a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA" device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false">
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"></a-scene>
<a-scene networked-scene="room: dev; debug: true; adapter: socketio;">
<a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA" device-orientation-permission ui="enabled: false">
<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"></a-scene>
<a-scene networked-scene="room: dev; debug: true; adapter: socketio;">
...
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 2):

Three problems in your code:

1. You're using an old version of A-Frame. Use 1.0.4 or newer.
2. It is `enabled: false` instead of `enabled: disabled`
3. There are multiple `<a-scene>` tags and only one is allowed. This how your `a-scene` markup should look like

```html
<a-scene 
   background="color: #FAFAFA" 
   device-orientation-permission-ui="enabled: false"
   vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"
   networked-scene="room: dev; debug: true; adapter: socketio;">
    ...
</a-scene>
```

[Corrected glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/well-nettle-tartan?path=index.html%3A21%3A67) that you can [run over HTTP](http://well-nettle-tartan.glitch.me/) and see that neither the enter VR button nor the permission dialog are displayed

Comment: Hello i tryed that code from the link you have posted and it is still there.

Comment: I edited the answer with a code sample. If you share code it will be easier to help. If the question is answered marking as correct will be appreciated

Comment: Hello i mange to figure it out. I had the code in the wrong place and somehow it was jaming things up. But i moved it to the top of the body of the code and now that seem to work and i was able to make it go away. Thank you

Comment: Glad hear. Marking the question as correct will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm Sorry i was wrong. I was trying to hide the VR button and i mnge to get that disabled. However the popup Access this site over HTTPS to enter VR mode and grant access to the device sensors. still remains.

Comment: Is not the example provided in the answer working for you to disable the HTTPS dialog? Use https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/vr-mode-ui.html#sidebar to disable the enter VR button.

Comment: Sharing your code on https://glitch.com/~aframe will make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: Here is the code https://glitch.com/edit/#!/bottlenose-jumpy-muscle?path=index.html%3A124%3A7 I never did glitch before so i hope i posted it right. The two lines after the <body>  has for the http popup and next line is for the disabling VR button. If i only disable the VR button that works. But when i put the other line of code in nothing gets disable. I'm ussing networked-aframe demo code from Hayden.

Comment: I edited the question and the answer addressing the problems in the glitch.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still new to aframe and scenes i know i was doing it wrong thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you can mark the question as correct. It will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Diego Marcos. For pointing me in the right direction. I know something was off. Still new to aframe and learning.

Joseph